# How to create the expression of three layers of sheets becoming soft and crushed?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm trying to make an animation like this (see the image)
[image]
I am currently using Fluid simulation to create this animation.
But I'm having trouble figuring out how to make it work because I've never heard that you can only use one liquid and not three.
(Am I right in understanding that in Fluid Simulation, multiple Domains cannot coexist, and there must be only one Flow (Liquid) corresponding to a Domain?)

My idea is to render each layer with a background transparency and combine it with the background, etc. to make a single video.
However, I think this method will inevitably result in a sense of discomfort.

Is there a better way?
[image]

Comment: You could try Flip Fluid addon, it's paid but has a demo so you can generate color attributes for your layers and use that in cycles... but colors will tend to blend. Not sure a fluid simulation is a good solution, maybe use it as a reference and then fake it with lattice modifier and shapekeys?

Comment: @calambre So sorry for late reply. And thank you so much for polite message! I checked about Flip Fluid, but it is little too much for me.. Then I tried lattice and shapekeys! And it worked!! I really apliciate you! I was pressed for time so you save me!

Comment: ok, good it worked for you!